# Change attributes of a UICollectionViewCell in didSelectItemAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am configuring a `UICollectionViewCell` in a subclass, it adds 2 subviews to the `contentView` property, both are `UIImageView` and both have the `hidden` property set to `YES`. These subviews are "checked" and "unchecked" images that overlay the primary UIImageView in the cell to indicate whether or not the current cell is selected using UICollectionView's "multiple select" feature.

When the cell is tapped, `collectionView:didSelectItemAtIndexPath:` is called on the delegate, and I'd like to `setHidden:NO` on the "checked" UIImageView. Calling this on the cell does nothing at all -- the cell is seemingly locked in its originally drawn state.

Is it possible to make changes to a cell outside `collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:`? I have tried manually adding subviews within `collectionView:didSelectItemAtIndexPath:`, but it just makes absolutely no change to the UI. I have verified that the delegate method is getting called, it's just not making my cell changes.

```
- (void) collectionView(UICollectionView *)cv didSelectItemAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    ShotCell *cell = [self collectionView:cv cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    UILabel *testLabel = UILabel.alloc.init;
    testLabel.text = @"FooBar";
    testLabel.sizeToFit;
    [cell.contentView.addSubview testLabel];
}
```

Comment: You can absolutely change the cell in `didSelectItemAtIndexPath`. You're probably just got a mistake in your code. please post your `didSelectItemAtIndexPath`.

Comment: Updated to add the `didSelectItemAtIndexPath`. Really not doing anything crazy and it doesn't choke on my method calls. It just doesn't update the UI.

Comment: try it  [cell.contentView checkImageHighlightedView].setHidden(NO);

Comment: `contentView` is just an object on the cell that holds subviews -- `checkImageHighlightedView` is a property on the cell, despite being added as a subview to `contentView`.

Comment: What kind of syntax is [cell checkImageHighlightedView].setHidden(NO)? Does that even compile?

Comment: Sorry, syntax isn't the problem: [[cell checkImageHighlightedView] setHidden:NO];

Comment: Please post `ShotCell`. I'd guess that in `checkImageHighlightedView`, you're trying to get a handle on your images to set their hidden properties, but you're getting `nil`.

Comment: Simplified it further so the UICollectionViewCell subclass doesn't even come into play. Simply tried adding a label as a subview, still nothing changed in the UI.

Comment: You need to call reloadData or reloadItemsAtIndexPaths: before the UI will be updated.

Comment: @rdelmar That's really expensive and it deselects everything -- are you sure that's the only way to update the UI?

Comment: It's not expensive if you only update the items that need to be using reloadItemsAtIndexPaths:. I'm not positively sure it's the only way, but it's the only way I've ever seen.

Comment: @rdelmar The bigger problem is that it deselects the cell, which is the opposite of what I want -- after all I'm making edits to the cell when `didSelectItemAtIndexPath` is called.

Comment: Well, you didn't mention that you were making edits to the cell in your question. What are you doing in the cell other than unhiding this checkmark?

Comment: No other edits. But my point is that `reloadItemsAtIndexPaths` deselects the cell, which doesn't help since I'm trying to add the checkmark upon selection (using `allowsMultipleSelection` on the collectionView)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34963/discussion-between-rdelmar-and-bensie)

Comment: I've posted a [sample project](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2183704/Change%20Cells.zip) for you that demonstrates a) adding a subview to the `contentView` of a cell and b) modifying that subview in `didSelectItemAtIndexPath`. Maybe you can compare with your code and spot find the issue. But it would really be ideal if you could post more of your code.

Comment: @TimothyMoose Thanks for the sample project. Any reason you used your `collectionView:configureCell:atIndexPath:` instead of built-in Apple APIs? I will post more code shortly.

Comment: The sample project uses my [TLIndexPathTools](http://tlindexpathtools.com) library, which provides a default implementation of `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, which calls `configureCell:atIndexPath:`. I like this approach because I can reconfigure the cell directly from anywhere (not just in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`).

Comment: @TimothyMoose Go ahead and post your sample project as an answer and I'll accept it. Using your code verbatim worked perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The way you're trying to do this is incorrect. You need to keep a reference to the selected cell or cells in a property. In this example, I use an array to hold index paths of the selected cells, then check whether the index path passed in to cellForItemAtIndexPath is contained in that array. I unselect the cell if you click on one that's already selected:

```
@interface ViewController ()
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSArray *theData;
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSMutableArray *paths;
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.paths = [NSMutableArray new];
    self.theData = @[@"One",@"Two",@"Three",@"Four",@"Five",@"Six",@"Seven",@"Eight"];
    [self.collectionView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"CVCell" bundle:nil] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cvCell"];

    UICollectionViewFlowLayout *flowLayout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
    [flowLayout setScrollDirection:UICollectionViewScrollDirectionVertical];
    [self.collectionView setCollectionViewLayout:flowLayout];
}

-(NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return self.theData.count;
}

-(CVCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"cvCell";
    CVCell *cell = (CVCell *) [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    cell.label.text = self.theData[indexPath.row];
    if ([self.paths containsObject:indexPath]) {
        [cell.iv setHidden:NO]; // iv is an IBOutlet to an image view in the custom cell
    }else{
        [cell.iv setHidden:YES];
    }
    return cell;
}

-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if ([self.paths containsObject:indexPath]) {
        [self.paths removeObject:indexPath];
    }else{
        [self.paths addObject:indexPath];
    }

    [self.collectionView reloadItemsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath]];
}

- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

        return CGSizeMake(150, 150);
}
```

Comment: Thank you @rdelmar, I think yours should be selected as the more correct and complete answer